# sw_urdf_exporter preview and sw crash

Tags: ros, coordinate, sw-urdf-exporter, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I have finished to **specify link and joint** at sw_urdf_exporter plugin, while other settings are set to be **automatic**, I click **preview**. The green process in the bottom loads a while and **SW crashes and throws error**.

I check [issue posted here](https://bitbucket.org/brawner/sw2urdf/issues/20/solidworks-urdf-exporter-does-not-create) and realize that the **reference coordinate system** and **axis** should be specified in the model before export. Am I right?

But instead, my model file type is **STEP**, where **assembly relations, reference coordinate system and axis do not exist**. So, in order to proceed with export urdf, should I add reference coordinate system and axis **mannually** for model?

If so, it is a pretty time-cosuming, in other words, **using original assembly file which contains assembly relation is the correct way to export urdf. Am I right?**   However, exporter plugin might be only fit to SW2012, original assembly is built in newer version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251639/sw_urdf_exporter-preview-and-sw-crash/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-01-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Panason](https://answers.ros.org/users/44410/panason/) on 2019-08-26**:
no need to assign reference frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So, in order to proceed with export urdf, should I add reference coordinate system and axis mannually for model?

If you want to have joints in your exported URDF: yes.

> If so, it is a pretty time-cosuming, in other words, using original assembly file which contains assembly relation is the correct way to export urdf. Am I right?

That would certainly seem to be the most straightforward way of doing it, yes.

> However, exporter plugin might be only fit to SW2012, original assembly is built in newer version.

I would try the plugin with a newer version of SW. It can work, it's just not supported / recommended.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-10**:
I tried the export process on SW2012 and failed, however I succeeded on SW2015 using other's PC. Maybe sth wrong with my SW2012.

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-10**:
I asked someone, he told me that, he used to turn step file into assembly file, after adding assembly relation. If  assembly relation exists, can both reference coordinate systems and reference axes be automatic detected with plugin, without mannually specifying?